# Prevent browser automatically launched when join to open wifi

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-note-3, captive-portal

How to prevent browser to automatically launched when I join to a wifi network with captive portal? i.e. with note 3

Comment: Well, I don't think that browser open automatically when you're connected with an open Wi-Fi rather than it shows you are notification that inorder to access wi-fi network you need to sign in or..... etc.

Comment: it is, in note 3 atleast. Browser automatically pop up when join open wifi with captive portal

Comment: Well, I am not familiar with it ! Maybe because I haven't used Note 3 anyway better would be to wait a bit more while to see if other users have something to talk about it !

Comment: You got that problem only with your WiFi connection or with other WiFi connections too ?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps for prevent the auto launch browser.

1. Go to Settings > WiFi settings
2. Long-press on Connection
3. Select "Modify network config"
4. Check the "Show advanced options" box.
5. Select proxy settings to Manual
6. Proxy host name , input the value from `192.168.1.1` to `192.168.1.225`
7. Proxy port = input one of them "8080" , "3128" , "80"
8. Press the "Save".
9. Turn wifi off and the On, you will not see the Popup browser.
10. Now repeat the steps from 1 ~ 4
11. And revert back the proxy settings to "None".

It's Done. You will be fine with this network.